# None of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types (in MFC / C++ project)

Tags: c++, mfc

I have copied some code from another project which I downloaded (and which compiled fine) and get the compiler error message when compiling the same code ( a file called player.cpp) in my own project:

Error   1   error C2665: 'MATExceptions::MATExceptions' : none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types  c:\users\daniel\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\mytest1\mytest1\player.cpp    137 1   Test1

The error occurs on this line in player.cpp:

```
        EXCEP(DirectSoundErr::GetErrDesc(hres), _T("Player::CreateDS DirectSoundCreate"));
```

Here is the definition of EXCEP and GetErrDesc:

```
#define EXCEP(/*const wchar_t * */ desc, /*const wchar_t * */ from) throw( MATExceptions(__LINE__,  _T(__FILE__), 0, from, desc) );

CComBSTR DirectSoundErr::GetErrDesc(HRESULT hres)
{
switch(hres)
{
    case DSERR_ALLOCATED : 
        return _T("The request failed because resources, such as a 
        priority level, were already in use by another caller.");               
...
    default : return _T("Unknown error");
}
}
```

I don't know what is different (as I have not changed the source file player.cpp).  Could it be due to different compiler settings in my project compared to the original (how would I check this)?

Comment: Why do you use `TCHAR`, when only `wchar_t` is acceptable?

Comment: The "other" project is probably only built for Unicode while yours isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the EXCEP definition to the following:

```
#define EXCEP(desc, from) throw(MATExceptions(__LINE__, (wchar_t *)(__FILE__), 0, (wchar_t *)from, (wchar_t *)desc));
```

...and changed the call from:

```
EXCEP(DirectSoundErr::GetErrDesc(hres), _T("Player::CreateDS DirectSoundCreate"));
```

to:

```
EXCEP(DirectSoundErr::GetErrDesc(hres), "Player::CreateDS DirectSoundCreate");
```

Is that acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

The original "new" can be killed by defining these in project (since Visual Studio 2015 I guess):

`__PLACEMENT_NEW_INLINE
__PLACEMENT_VEC_NEW_INLINE`

But once they are gone, they are gone. Now you need to make sure to include the project-specific header file which redefines them.